# How can I modify the layout of slidingtab in the lockscreen?,is 

Tags: android

In the lockscreen ,the layout of slidingtab is vertical,how can i modify it to "horizontal"?

I set :

```
  <com.android.internal.widget.SlidingTab
      android:id="@+id/tab_selector"
      ***android:orientation="horizontal"***
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"            
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
      />
```

But the draw of the slidingtab is not modify,is always vertical.